# O(n*log n) + O(m*log m) vs O((n+m)log(n+m))

Tags: complexity-theory

Which complexity is better `O(n*log n) + O(m*log m) vs O((n+m)log(n+m)) where n>1 and m>1`.
Can anyone give mathematical proof also?

Comment: My gut feeling says they are equally good.

Comment: @Erich Kitzmueller Can you prove it mathematically or logically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my reasoning why I think they are equally good:

Case A: both m and n grow equally fast:

```
O(n*log n) + O(m*log m) = 2*O(n*log n) = O(n*log n)   // positive constant removed
O((n+m)log(n+m)) = O((2n)log(2n)) = O((n)log(n))      // positive constants removed
```

Case B: either m or n grows faster than the other (assuming n, w.l.o.g.)

```
O(n*log n) + O(m*log m) = O(n*log n)    // slower growing part removed
O((n+m)log(n+m)) = O(n*log n)           // slower growing part removed
```

Comment: I understood your answer except ( w.l.o.g.). Thanks for helping!

Comment: w.l.o.g. = without loss of generality. I assumed `n` grows faster than `m`, but obviously the same argument works as well when we assume that `m` grows faster than `n`.